# Ускорение метода распределяющего объекты по разным коллекциям

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции

Есть несколько коллекций:

```
private List<Order> fstBookBUY;
private List<Order> fstBookSELL;
private List<Order> sndBookBUY;
private List<Order> sndBookSELL;
private List<Order> trdBookBUY;
private List<Order> trdBookSELL;
```

И есть метод который заполняет их данными распределяя из входной коллекции:

```
    private void segregateBooks(List<Order> orders) {
        for (Order order : orders) {
            if ("book-1".equals(order.getBook())) {
                if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                    fstBookBUY.add(order);
                } else {
                    fstBookSELL.add(order);
                }
            }

            if ("book-2".equals(order.getBook())) {
                if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                    sndBookBUY.add(order);
                } else {
                    sndBookSELL.add(order);
                }
            }

            if ("book-3".equals(order.getBook())) {
                if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                    trdBookBUY.add(order);
                } else {
                    trdBookSELL.add(order);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Я хочу ускорить этот метод, если это возможно. Может есть какой-то хитрый способ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложно что либо советовать не понимая конечной цели. На вопрос "Каким молотком проще забивать шурупы" хочется не советовать модель молотка, а намекнуть на отвертку.

Если вам в итоге надо по имени книги и типу ордера делать выборки, то можно воспользоваться таким способом.

```
private Map<String, Order> books = new HashMap<>();

private void segregateBooks(List<Order> orders) {
    for (Order order : orders) {
        books.put(order.getBook() + order.getOperation(), order);
    }
}
```

Если нужен доступ к спискам по атрибутам, то просто делаете вложенную конструкцию

```
Map<String, Map<String, Order>> books = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Order>>();

private void segregateBooks(List<Order> orders) {
    for (Order order : orders) {
        Map<String, Order> inner = books.get(order.getBook());
        if(inner == null){
            inner = new HashMap<String, Order>();
            books.put(order.getBook(), inner);
        }
        inner.put(order.getOperation(), order)
    }
}
```

и т.д.

Comment: Чувствую что ваш вариант оч хороший но не понимаю как работает. Вот объект inner он же временный цикл пройдет и он исчезнет. Если он не равен нул то вы записываете в него операцию и ордер Но зачем? Что дальше он же сотрется ...

Comment: @Павел с чего бы ему пропадать? Он помещается с books и остается там. У HashMap метод put() работает со значением, а не ссылкой. А get() наоборот.

Comment: @Павел однако в `Map books` ведь сохранится. Возможно, интуитивно понятнее такой код: `books.putIfAbsent(order.getBook(), new HashMap<>()); Map<String, Order> inner = books.get(order.getBook()); inner.put(order.getOperation(), order);`, который делает то же самое.

Comment: Да тот который в теле ифа это понятно я имею в виду тот который после ифа идет т.е. последняя строка как этот результат сохраняется? Ведь объект inner взаимодействует с books только в теле ифа а если поток выполнения туда не заходит то как тогда он в букс сохраняется?

Comment: @Павел все очень просто. Сначала мы присваиваем `inner` ссылку на объект, которых достаем `books.get(order.getBook())`. Если он null, то инстанцируем новый `HashMap` и кладем его в `books`. В последней строке `inner` и объект в `books` - это один и тот же объект. При следующей итерации цикла у нас новый локальный `inner`, так как мы его заново определяем `Map<String, Order> inner = ...`

Comment: @rjhdby кажется подразобрался но еще один момент: inner.put(order.getOperation(), order) у нас же в карте не может быть одинаковых ключей , а мы в качестве ключа добавляем getOperation() который всего 2 значения имеет, как так?

Comment: @Павел сделайте так например `Map<String, Map<String, List<Order>>>`. Вообще, такие задачи всегда надо рассматривать с точки зрения компромисса между простотой разбора и простотой работы с результатом. В вашем случае я вообще бы не парился разбором исходного листа, а просто сделал бы методы `getBuyOrders(String bookId)` и `getSellOrders(String bookId)` в которых тупо циклом перебирал список и возвращал нужное

Answer (score 1):

Используйте многопоточность. На Java8:

```
private void segregateBooks(List<Order> orders) {

 orders.parallelStream().forEach(order -> {

       if ("book-1".equals(order.getBook())) {
            if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                fstBookBUY.add(order);
            } else {
                fstBookSELL.add(order);
            }
        }

        if ("book-2".equals(order.getBook())) {
            if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                sndBookBUY.add(order);
            } else {
                sndBookSELL.add(order);
            }
        }

        if ("book-3".equals(order.getBook())) {
            if ("BUY".equals(order.getOperation())) {
                trdBookBUY.add(order);
            } else {
                trdBookSELL.add(order);
            }
        }
 })
}
```